What was that story of Bhagwan Krishn and a hunter?
I've once read a story about Bhagwan Krishn where he saved a Hiran (deer) from the Hunter, and then educated the hunter to give up on meat and killing animals. Telling him it's adharma to take one's life when you can have other dharmic means to live
Please if you can find that story from somewhere do share.
